# How do I add extra fields in Dokan?

Tags: wordpress, tags, dokan

Good Day.
I am developing a multivendor website for my client and I used Dokan. My client would like his vendors to add a (Sample Product Price) and (Bulk Product Price).
Is there any way to add those fields?
He also would like his vendors to add custom tags to their products.
Regards,

Comment: Please add your own research effort and why nothing of the found worked.

Comment: Hello jasie. I couldn't find any related topics to my requirement. I asked wedevs team and they didn't bother to help me. All I found are some function.php codes for adding a website field, an extra purchase code text box, a vendor biography and so on. I didn't find what I need even in stackoverflow. So I am humbly asking for your kind help.

Comment: Did you go though the official documentation? https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan

Comment: Did you consider this? https://wedevs.com/docs/wp-user-frontend-pro/acf-integration/

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is when adding a custom field it will appear in the a special area called (Post). I need it to be appeared when the vendor is adding a new product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to dokan plugin directory. then go to the below path

**1) templates/products/new-product-single.php**

**2) templates/products/new-product.php**

You can override the new-product.php and new-product-single.php file in your child theme and then add your field. However, there are some other steps required to successfully save them.

These below hooks to save and update the field data.

```
do_action( 'dokan_new_product_added', $product_id, $post_data ); 
do_action( 'dokan_product_updated', $post_id );
```

Comment: I added the code. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: did you tested?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: If my answer helped you then you can accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: It is done. I appreciate your kindness